# add the position of the element to the element in the list

Tags: python-2.7

Define a function add_position_to_content(...)  which receives a list with integer numbers (possibly the empty list)  and modifies this same list, in place, adding to each element the position where the element is.

As an example, the following code fragment:
lint = [10,10,10,10]
add_position_to_content(lint)

print lint
should produce the output:
[10, 11, 12, 13]

```
 lint = [10,10,10,10]
 def add_position_to_content(lint):
   for i in range (len(lint)):
     lint[i] += ###### what would I write here? #####
   return lint
 print add_position_to_content(lint)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def add_position_to_content(lint):
    for i in range (len(lint)):
        lint[i] += i
    return lint
```

or

```
def add_position_to_content(lint):
    lint[:] = [elem + index for index, elem in enumerate(lint)]
    return lint
```

Comment: Just to note that the second option doesn't meet *and modifies this same list, in place*

Comment: @JonClements: fixed. also, I don't really see any sense in returning if you're modifying original element (except being able to print), but it was that way in the question.

Comment: Nor I - also note the update still doesn't modify `lint`... :) (it's also missing some stuff...)

Comment: You could use `lint[:] = ` instead to do so